# Even/odd numbers and modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $x, y, z$ are integers such that $z(x+y)+y(x+z)$ is an odd integer.

1. $x^2+yz$ is odd.
2. $y^2+xz$ is odd.
3. $z^2+xy$ is even.

Which of the above statement(s) holds? I started off with the assumption that

$$z(x+y)+y(x+z) = x(y+z) + 2yz\equiv x(y+z)\equiv 1\pmod {2}$$

Which is true if and only if $x\equiv 1\mod{2}$ and $y+z\equiv 1\pmod{2}$ and so $y\equiv 1-z\pmod{2}$.

$$x^2+yz\equiv 1+(1-z)z\pmod{2}\tag{1}$$

That's odd.

$$y^2+xz\equiv y^2+z\equiv (1-z)^2+z\pmod{2}\tag{2}$$

That's odd.

$$z^2+xy\equiv z^2+y\equiv z^2+(1-z)\pmod{2}\tag{3}$$

That's, again, odd.

Comment: Without reading what you actually did, I can tell you what I would do. There are two choices each for $x, y, z$ mod $2$. I would make a table and try them all, and reduce this to a thoughtless computation.

Comment: @davidlowryduda That's true, yes.

Comment: However, is the work I did in my post also meaningful?

Comment: Based on your work, $x$ must be odd, and $y$ and $z$ must be of opposite parity. So, yes, as you noted, all of the given expressions are odd.

Comment: You may be missing part of the point of the comment of @davidlowryduda.  In a problem like this, it *looks* as if you will be able to tell whether $~x~$ is odd or even, whether $~y~$ is odd or even, and whether $~z~$ is odd or even.  Perhaps, perhaps not.  I would make such an attempt **Step 1**, for this particular problem, before examining the given choices.

Comment: Exactly one of $x,y,z$ has to be even, otherwise $z(x+y)+y(x+z)$ is even, since both terms would be even. In your post you checked what happens if $y$ or $z$ are even. Now you only need to check what happens if $x$ is even and the others are odd. In fact with this reasoning you do exactly the same work as just doing case distinctions for all the possible combinations of $(x,y,z)$ mod 2, so I would suggest to do that (as @davidlowryduda suggested) with that kind of problems, since it minimizes the chance for mistakes.

Comment: You *can* start as suggested in the first comment, but what you actually did looks perfectly sound to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to distinguish between two different situations:

1. It is *necessary*, given $z(x+y)+y(x+z)$ is odd, that $x^2+yz$ is odd;
2. It is *possible*, given $z(x+y)+y(x+z)$ is odd, that $x^2+yz$ is odd (or equivalently, $x^2+yz$ is *consistent* with the given information, but it is not guaranteed).

The wording of the question strongly points towards wanting you to prove 1, not 2, but your work is much more consistent with proving 2 (and the equivalent statements for the other expressions).

So we want to see which of the given statements can be deduced from the given information. As you have demonstrated, we know that $x$ and $y+z$ are both odd. We can then reduce the given expressions mod 2, making use of the fact that $a^2 \equiv a \mod 2$. For example:

$$\begin{eqnarray} z^2 + xy & \equiv & z + 1 y \mod 2 \\
& \equiv & z + y \mod 2 \\
& \equiv & 1 \mod 2 \end{eqnarray}$$

so we know that $z^2 + xy$ is guaranteed to be odd, making 3 *always* false. You can do something similar for 1 and 2 to find out whether they are also forced to be a particular parity.

To give an example of an expression whose parity is *not* guaranteed to be one way or the other, consider something like $x + z$ - we know that $x$ is definitely odd, but it's possible for $z$ to be even *or* odd so we don't actually know either way.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- $z(x+y)+y(x+z) \text { odd}\iff x(y+z) \text { odd}$ then the only possibilities are $$(x,y,z)=(\text {odd,even,odd }),(\text {odd,odd,even })$$ In both cases we have $$1.\space x^2+yz\space  \text {is odd}$$
However, when $(x,y,z)=(\text {odd,even,odd })$ one has also
$2.\space y^2+xz$ is odd too.